# Pre-populate fields in Sitecore 9 Forms

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have a requirement to pre-populate a Sitecore 9 form field from a referring page

Now in WFFM you could use the "ReadQueryString" checkbox:

[image]

or you could make use of the Rules Engine inside the Form Designer:

[image]

Does anyone know if it's possible in Sitecore Forms OOTB? Or is this something custom that I need to introduce in order to create the same functionality?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Sitecore 9.0 it is not possible OOTB.

However, in Sitecore 9.1 they did announce field prefilling as a new feature so if upgrading when this version becomes available (should be very soon now) is an option I would do that.

If that is not an option, you could check the extension my colleague Bart has written: https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions They include prefilling based on xConnect data, but you can extend this with other sources (like the querystring as you require). More info on his solution on his [blog](https://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/prefill-fields-in-sitecore-forms).

Comment: You can also refer to this blog post from Bart:- http://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/prefill-fields-in-sitecore-forms/